# Can you help identify a pistol believed to be Ottoman Empire (Turkish)?

Tags: weapons, identification

[image: Pistol locking mechanism]Trying to identify a pistol believed to be Ottoman Empire (Turkish[image: )]

Comment: Do you have a picture showing the other side with the lock mechanism?

Comment: On the upper part, where the cannon joins to the hilt, there has to be three or four symbols engraved, one next to a pin and the rest a little separated. Without those symbols, it's impossible to give details.

Comment: Read the highly-upvoted comment on your other question yet?